# After upgrading to Android Studio 3.5, native library doesn't get packaged into APK anymore

Tags: java-native-interface, native, android-studio-3.5

My Android App (API28 UI with a native c++ library) was perfectly working until I decided to upgrade to Android Studio 3.5 from Android Studio 3.4 (latest ver).

Being the code ***unchanged*** (besides the upgrade wizard changes), the issue is at runtime, when *System.loadLibrary("gtaSDK")* gets executed, I get the following exception:

```
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gta.appmodule-TGjLG0gzxmY0yJQ8W--s3Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gta.appmodule-TGjLG0gzxmY0yJQ8W--s3Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]] couldn't find "libgtaSDK.so"
```

It seems, for some reason, that the native "gtaSDK" library (which is on an external module, not directly linked into the main project) doesn't get packaged into APK anymore (although the *libgtaSDK.so* does get correctly generated)... but can't figure out why as it was all working perfectly before the upgrade.
Build Gradle is the latest 3.5.0

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Same issue! Also, I found this ticket https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139911897, but it has no solution yet